# How to reduce the time when having a lot of records in Datatable,Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I'm have a problem when i want to edit the cell in each record in datatable. The records of datatable is about 200k records and 12 columns. It used a lot of time (maybe more than one days).

This my code.

```
Table.Columns.Add("DateTime", typeof(String));

for (int i = 0; i < Table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   if (Table.Rows[i][9].ToString() != "")
   {
      Table.Rows[i][9] = Table.Rows[i][9].ToString().Replace("'", "");
   }
   Table.Rows[i][12] = DateTime.Now;
}
```

How can i reduce the time to process these datatable and view these datatable in the datagridview?

Comment: Why do you have such a high volume of data on the client side? Can you specify the whole workflow? Usually, client application should process a much lower data volume.

Comment: is this win form or web form? 200K data is pulled from database? why dont you move logic in database?

Comment: can u guide me the maximum records that the datatable can keep? @Alexei

Comment: it's a winform application.I'm reading the excel file and filter the data in my datatable. @Viru

Comment: can you post full code? and are you sure the populating the data table takes time or data rendering is taking time?

Comment: with such a huge data, I would recommend you to use pagination in data grid view

Comment: I am not able to understand your code. Initially you mentioned that you are reading from excel but now it seems you are using SQL. It would be better if you update the complete code in question which can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: sry for these bad code. I would like to tell you about the workflow.

first i read the excel file to datatable and then pass these datatable to Time Stamp in each record. After that i will bulkinsert these table into SQL.

The problem cause when i timestamp. It used a lot of time.

@Viru

Comment: why are you timestamping each record in c#. If you are bulk inserting it in SQL then let SQL take care of updating timestamp for each record